# Opencart not adding product options to cart

Tags: opencart

I have an opencart site developed for a client and 99% works fine except one annoying bug which is driving my client nuts, if a customer adds a product to the cart, it doesn't send the product option e.g. colour. and this then doesn't appear on the order in the admin, and my client has to ring the customer to get the order details.

My first thought was a server issue (max_vars etc) but this isn't the issue, I added another theme and it works fine.

I have checked my code and it's identical to the default theme (which works fine) and the only errors in the OC errors.txt is a category_id which shouldn't affect the cart system.

The website is http://goo.gl/2naK6n if you go to cycle and select the 3rd item in the top row.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: don't know what your exact problem is, but judging the situation this is clearly a problem with ajax posting, the option details are normally added from the start as soon as you click add to cart, maybe your form is not submitting correctly and options are omitted, or maybe you moved options around outside the div that the data are read from. Bottom line is this is a difficult issue to track but ajax debugging when button add to cart is clicked is where i would start.

Comment: There are no errors in the Firebug JS console and the code is near identical to the default theme except I added an extra div. The pastebin of my product.tpl is http://pastebin.com/tSkkLEiQ

Comment: @GarethGillman I have same problem. Sometimes product options are not added to the cart, then accidentaly everything is working fine. Any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Lets see i can not seem to find the  exact error, and it really is a hustle to check the whole code so i will make a suggestion hoping it will fix it :), you should try and change the ajax code in the `$('#button-cart').bind('click', function() {` by replacing:

```
data: $('input[type=\'text\'], input[type=\'hidden\'], input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked, select, textarea'),
```

with

```
data: $('.product-info input[type=\'text\'], .product-info input[type=\'hidden\'], .product-info input[type=\'radio\']:checked, .product-info input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, .product-info select, .product-info textarea'),
```

with this approach you specify in more accurate way the relation between products and options,

hope it solves your problem.